# Padding (left, top, right, bottom) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, padding

What I want to have is a button with a bit of left and right padding.
I can set the MinWidth to some val, but if the Content will be changed it may not be enough.

```
 <Button MinWidth="75" Padding="2" Content="It speaks!" />
```

Is it possible to simulate something like Padding.left/right in WPF?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I believe both Margins and Padding work with Thickness, which can either be described as a single integer or as a list of four: `Padding="3, 10, 30, 10"` for instance.

The order is left, top, right, bottom - which is annoyingly not the same as CSS.

Comment: you can probably remember it this way. Both are clockwise, css starts at top (top, right, bottom, left), wpf starts at left (left, top, right, bottom). That said, i agree that it's annoyingly inconsistent. css is the standard, not wpf.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not familiar with WPF but I think it can be

```
<Button MinWidth="75" Padding="left,top,right,bottom" Content="It speaks!" />
```

So for 2 left padding, 3 top, 4 right, and 5 bottom:

```
<Button MinWidth="75" Padding="2,3,4,5" Content="It speaks!" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if it had the same order as CSS? Unfortunately it doesn't - it's left, top, right, bottom. Heaven forbid that Microsoft should ever support an established standard.

Comment: True, but it's rare that Microsoft do in a way everyone would like to.

Comment: To be fair to Microsoft, they're using a ordering convention they created back in the Win32 days - LONG before CSS was around.  CSS is the new kid on the block in this case, not Microsoft.

Comment: Clocks have been around for longer than this though. And they go "top, right, bottom, left", same as CSS.

Comment: @Lunivore: Yes, but Cartesian coordinates go x-before-y

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not a coordinate; it's a border. It has four values, not two. At the very least I would expect it to follow the order of polar coordinates: right, top, left, bottom. Even if they followed cartesian I would expect to do all x before y, lowest first: left, right, bottom, top - or highest first: right, left, top, bottom - or even with the y starting at the top the way graphics do it: left, right, top, bottom - but all of these would involve following any kind of established conventional standard, which... well... it's Microsoft.